# How to open a mobile application deep link from server like expressjs

Tags: android, react-native, express, android-deep-link

When hit a endpoint called /redirect, i want the server to respond with res.redirect("app://login"), but the deep link url("app://login") is getting appended to the relative url of endpoint, like this /redirect/app://login.

How can i redirect back to mobile application from a server using a deep link?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. The express command `res.redirect("app://login")` correctly redirects me from `http://localhost/redirect` to `app://login`, as expected.

Comment: how are you calling the http://localhost/redirect from the frontend?

Comment: It worked. I just have to try some other hostname instead of app.